# Collision detection in 2D game without tiles XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, tile, pixel-perfect

I'm working on a XNA platform game and would need some help with the collision. The game takes place in a cave and the problem is that the art style will be sketchy and therefore the terrain( the caves) will differ a LOT, so I can't use tiles. But I need to check pixel perfect collision on the character and the cave but I can't figure out how to do so when I can't place rectangles around every tiles since there are none.

I have thought about it a lot came up with some ideas:

-One big rectangle around the whole level and one around the character and use pixel perfect collision. But I don't think that will work since the rectangle will include the background as well.

-Place out rectangles manually. Very ugly code and may cause a lot of bugs and errors.

-Use tiles anyway and have hundreds of tile types. Again, very ugly code and it just seems wrong.

-Use a collision engine. I would preferably make the game from scratch.

I'm sorry if I've explained badly, but it's a rather complicated problem(for me at least) and I can't find any solution around the net. Would be very glad for any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use per-pixel collision detection to do what you're trying to. You could have your character, and make his texture transparent (using the image's `alpha`) except for the actual character. Then you could have the `terrain` texture which would be your cave. Make the parts of the cave the character should be able to move transparent, so that you can have another texture which will be the background of the whole level. Here's a rough example:

Character (pink BG is transparent:)

[image]

Cave (white is transparent)

[image]

Background:

[image]

All three added together:

[image]

That's just to give you a very rough idea (since i just googled the background and drew the cave in paint). Then you could use alpha pixel collision detection between the cave texture (NOT the cave background) and the character texture. See [this](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel) for a tutorial on how you could easily use per-pixel collision. HTH. Here is some collision code you could use (`rectangleA` should be the character's rectangle, `dataA` the character's pixel Data, `rectangleB` the rectangle of the cave (which will probably be the whole screen), and `dataB` the pixel data of the cave (NOT THE BACKGROUND)) Since you aren't using the pixel data of the background image, the collision won't be checked with this data:

```
    /// <param name="rectangleA">Bounding rectangle of the first sprite</param>
    /// <param name="dataA">Pixel data of the first sprite</param>
    /// <param name="rectangleB">Bouding rectangle of the second sprite</param>
    /// <param name="dataB">Pixel data of the second sprite</param>
    /// <returns>True if non-transparent pixels overlap; false otherwise</returns>
    static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA,
                                Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
    {
        // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

        // Check every point within the intersection bounds
        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                // Get the color of both pixels at this point
                Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
                                     (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
                                     (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

                // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                {
                    // then an intersection has been found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @davidsbro! I still need to place out rectangles to have pixel per pixel collision, right? Or have I missunderstood the concept of per-pixel collision? 

If I've understood it right, it checks if two rectangles are colliding and then checks the colors inside the rectangles to see if it collides. Is that right? If taht's the case, won't I still need to place out rectangles around the cave?

Comment: Yes, you're right @user3313308. But you'll only have to have two rectangles; one around the whole cave texture (which would be the whole screen probably) and one around the player; you shouldn't need more than two. The link I provided is a very simple per-pixel collision project so you can get an idea of what it would be like. LMK if anything's unclear.

Comment: Actually, you would only need one rectangle for the character if the cave encompasses the whole screen. Then all you'd have to do is check each pixel (from the cave texture and character texture) in the character's rectangle

Comment: Won't the background's pixels be included with the rectangle around the whole screen? I understand how to do this without a background now, but if I include the background, won't it be counted as pixels? Thank you for taking time to explain to me!

Comment: No, not if you only check the cave texture for the collision. The rectangle around the whole screen just checks to see if the player is colliding with it (which it will always be). So the collision boils down to checking the `cave` texture (not the background) against the character texture. Sure, I'm more than happy to help! I'll add collision code to my answer to help explain.

Comment: I think I understand now, I'll try it out later today and report the results tomorrow! What I still don't understand though i _why_ the background doesn't interfere, we never mention the cave texture anywhere so what's the difference between the background and the cave texture making the collision detection skip the background's pixels?

Comment: What you need to do is compare the pixel data _from the cave texture_ to the data from the character texture. Since the background texture is (or should be) separate from the cave, the background is not in the collision detection. Good luck. Lmk how it goes.

Comment: I've gotten it to work, I understand everything now as well, thank you very much! Do you have any idea how to stop the character when he intersects though? So that he doesn't get stuck... I've only made space shooters before, that's why I'm not very familiar with this kind of programming.

Comment: Sure, glad I was able to help! To stop the character from getting stuck you could try moving him "back" a "frame" when he intersects, or deny movement if he is intersecting, etc. Also you could look at here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666507/boundingboxes-for-collision-detection-overlapping-and-causing-issues

Comment: Hi again! I've tried for one week now but I can't even get it close to working. Do you have any other links than that one?

Comment: What's your question? I'd be glad to help! I'm not aware of any other links, but maybe if you state your problem, I could help.

Comment: The problem is that I can't detect which way the collision is arriving from, if I knew that, I could simply move him back the way he came from. But since one of the rectangles covers the whole stage, I can't do a rectangle.top etc.

Also, when I tried to only check the collision from one direction(under the character), he sinks and then slowly moves up to the right place instead of teleporting there... Any ideas?

Comment: @user3313308 Well, if your player has a velocity, you could use that to detect which way the collision's arriving from. Or you could find where on the character texture the collision is, and use that. For example, if the collision pixel is on the right of the character, you know it arrived on the right.